# How to insert custom sample data in joomla 2.5.14

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have downloaded joomla 2.5.14, so my issue is while installing joomla i found an option install sample data and i also found this option under **Load sample data** 
(1b. Custom sample data can be inserted. To do this, choose an available sample data in the dropdown and click the Install Sample Data button)

But i cannot find a dropdown to select my sample data and install rather than installing the default sample data given by joomla. Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you insert your data per the documentation? If not, that would be a good place to start.

http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_Sample_Data